# Rational exponentiation?

Tags: exponentiation, fractions, rational-numbers

Consider the following operation:

$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^\frac{n}{m}$

where $a, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b, m\in\mathbb{N^*}$.

My question is: when the result is a rational number, how (formula or algorithm) do you compute $c\in\mathbb{Z}, d\in\mathbb{N^*}$ in:

$\frac{c}{d}=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^\frac{n}{m}$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126419/determine-if-p-qa-b-is-rational?rq=1

Comment: Here is a hint: If $x = 1.23456789$ is a rational number, then $x = \dfrac{123456789}{100,000,000}$.